# Filtering results with Distinct column drastically slows execution

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distinct

I wrote a custom RDD provider with spark and testing its execution time under SQL query. I am not sure that the internal mechanism for this provider is relevant for the question, but basically it's used to read data from local and remote files.

The issue: Running the query with `distinct` keyword (either for aggregative queries or not) has terrible effect on the performance of the query.

Example:

query: `select sourceip, sourceport, destinationport from table where destinationport=80`
execution time: 31527 ms

query: `select distinct sourceip, sourceport, destinationport from events where destinationport=80`
execution time: 57856 ms

This result is for a very small amount of data, when I try to run it on medium size dataset Spark crushes with 'Too many open files'.

The log:

> /tmp/spark-a47f859b-2a1f-4466-8333-0bf40c3968eb/executor-9c98264a-23a8-49b8-ab6f-ddf7349e0155/blockmgr-b73fc639-8705-4956-8652-e7300b35527a/3f/temp_shuffle_b4afe57f-9db1-4653-91c0-22d207933748 (Too many open files)

For perspective, using `distinct` crushes the cluster with 5 min of data whereas without `distinct` the server successfully runs 2 day queries.

Any ideas what might cause this problem?

P.S. I verified the number of open files and their limit using:

open files: `lsof | wc -l` resulted in ~1.4M
max open files: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` resulted in 9-42M (depending on machine - master had 9M)

Answer (score 0):

Following two steps help you to debug issue :

1) distinct() is definitely doing a shuffle across partitions. To see more of what's happening, run a .toDebugString on your RDD ?.

2) Can you check is your job is proper parallelized  use Spark UI for check ?

Also check your partitioning is it skew ,[here is link for further reading](https://datarus.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/fighting-the-skew-in-spark/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course your query will be slowdown if you have distinct in it.

```
select sourceip, sourceport, destinationport from table where destinationport=80
```

Here it is a simple select-filter query. So it doesn't need any shuffle. Spark will do the predicate pushdown and give result using only filter operation

Whereas

```
select distinct sourceip, sourceport, destinationport from events where destinationport=80
```

Here you have distinct. Which essentially asks spark to do shuffle. It will first filter out the result , then compute the hash value of each result then do the reduce operation to remove the duplicate results (Same hash multiple rows boils down to one row)

Now shuffle is a relatively expensive operation as it needs to send data over the network hence the second query will be significantly slower than the former